# Export NDVI from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, landsat, ndvi, google

I generated a Lansat 5 image NDVI in a rectangle of interest in Google Earth Engine.

After that, I tried to export the image to my Google Drive, but the final result does not load the usual values of an NDVI (-1 to +1), as is usually done in a GIS program (QGIS, ArcGIS, etc.). The DN has a single value (attached image).

How could I solve this?

My code is:

```
var imgL5 = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T2_TOA/LT05_226074_19850719');

var poly = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[ 
[-56.298454803020135,-20.398292995561647], 
[-56.298454803020135,-19.8799857811524], 
[-57.037285369426385,-19.8799857811524], 
[-57.037285369426385,-20.398292995561647] 
]])

var cortado = imgL5.clip(poly);

//Calc NDVI

var nir = cortado.select('B5');
var red = cortado.select('B4');
var NDVI = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red));

Map.addLayer(NDVI);

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: NDVI.float(),
  description: 'NDVI_9',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry,
  folder: 'GEE',
});


Map.setCenter(-56.67318953949383,-20.121019484901392, 10);
```

[image]

Comment: Did try to export the NDVI raster outside of google Drive? Also, in what type of file format the raster was exported ?

Comment: I did not try to export to another place of departure.
The output format is .tif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code. I only updated-  "region: poly" (and not-  "region: geometry") and it worked fine with Qgis. Maybe the region you defined in the export code was the problem ? [image]

BTW if you want your NDVI values to be between -1 to 1 you can use landsat5 surface reflectance: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LT05_C01_T1_SR . In your code you used top of atmosphere data and that's why there is values smaller then -1 .

Comment: Hello everyone, I apologize for the time lag. I tested some things and read the NDVI theory. Really, the correct thing is to use the image in SR (surface reflectance). As for geometry, I did correct it. I created a square in shp format in Qgis, then I uploaded it as a "table" and got the expected result. I thank everyone for their efforts, thank you very much.